# AWS /.ssh permission set 600 by mistake eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, session, amazon-ec2, ssh, permissions

I am getting error **Permission denied (publickey).** while connecting to ssh. So i was trying to set permission to 600 to the public and private files but **by mistake 600 permission given to  /.ssh**

I was previously able to connect ssh but by mistake i run chmod 600 /.ssh instead of /.ssh/latest-key.pem

Now i am getting error

```
eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

So **is there a way i can rechange /.ssh dir permission to 700?**

I have also tried to setup EC2 via AWS Session Manager and without SSH inbound rule but with no success.

Comment: Does you instance have connection to internet? Last I used Session Manager it needed either to be in a VPC with internet gateway or a NAT

Comment: Have you previously connected to this instance? Have you shown the full error message? It seems to be missing the instance identifier. Use `ssh -vvv ...` to see debug information for the ssh connection. Please Edit your Question and show us the command you are using and the debug output.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, i was previously able to connect ssh but by mistake i run chmod 600 /.ssh instead of /.ssh/latest-key-cci-prod.pem

Comment: @ErikAsplund please check my comment

Comment: If you think that is the cause, then did you try changing it back? `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein not able to connect SSH again after that execution.

Comment: Rather than making an assumption that the `chmod` was the cause, you can use `ssh -vvv ...` to activate debug output. Please Edit your Question and show us the command you are using and the debug output.